# PG::InvalidColumnReference: ERROR: for SELECT DISTINCT in Ruby on Rails app

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I have a query that looks like this:

```
 Person.where.not(first_name: nil).where.not("lower(first_name)  = ?", 'mike').order('RANDOM()').limit(6).pluck("distinct(lower(first_name))")
```

It returns me the following error when I try to run it:

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::InvalidColumnReference: ERROR:  for SELECT DISTINCT, ORDER BY expressions must appear in select list
LINE 1: ...AND (NOT (lower(first_name)  = 'mike'))  ORDER BY RANDOM() L...
```

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: try `Person.where.not(first_name: nil).where.not("lower(first_name)  = ?", 'mike').order('RANDOM()').limit(6).pluck("lower(first_name)").uniq` or `Person.where('first_name IS NOT NULL and lower(first_name) != ?', 'mike').order('RANDOM()').limit(6).pluck("lower(first_name)").uniq`

Answer (score 1):

```
Person.where.not(first_name: nil).where.not("lower(first_name)  = ?", 'mike').order('RANDOM()').limit(6).select("lower(first_name)").uniq
```

Since pluck will fire extra query so instead of pluck you should use select